# lollipop Brocho

Tags: blessing, food

What and which Brochos do you make on lollipops and Gum?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the brocho rishonah they're both shehakol.

For the brocho achronahs: none. Because almost never (and in case of gum never) eat a proper shiur.

Source: http://www.Brochos.com

Answer (score 1):

According to Shu"t Yishak Yeranen, Birkat Hashem, and Yaskil Avdi you don't bless on gum.